# determine whether dropdownlist is selected or not

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to send postdata thru ajax
The code tried so far,

```
 var $inputs = $('#myform :input');
 var values = {};
 $inputs.each(function(i,field) {


                      if($(this).is(':text'))
                      {
                             //alert("id : " + field.id + " value : "+ field.value);
                             values[field.id] = field.value
                      }
                      if($(this).is(":radio"))
                      {
                                var v = $(this).attr('checked')
                                if (v == true)
                                {
                                       values[this.name] = $(this).val()
                                       //alert($(this).attr('checked'))
                                }
                      }
                      if($(this).is(":checkbox"))
                      {
                           var v = $(this).attr('checked')
                           if (v == true)
                           {
                               values[this.name] = $(this).val()
                               //alert($(this).attr('checked'))
                           }
                      }
                      alert($(this).is(":hidden"))
                      if($(this).is(":hidden"))
                      {
                           values[field.name] = field.value
                      }
                      //alert("dropdownlist : " + $(this).is('option:selected'));
                      //values[field.id]  = field.value


                });
```

It works fine, but i want to determine 
whether dropdownlist is selected or not based
on it I need to add `values[field.id] = field.value`
Is there any way to find out about  dropdownlist
Similar to `$(this).is(':checkbox'),$(this).is(':text')`
Any help will be valuable

Answer (score 2):

You can check if it's a `<select>` element, like this:

```
$(this).is("select")
```

Since [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) takes any selector, just use an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) :)

From an overall perspective though, you seem to be replcating built-in functionality, take a look at [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), you can use this to do what you're already trying, for example:

```
$.post(url, $("#myform").serialize());
```

Comment: I have tried using serializeArray,
But in some cases I need to use id of an element
Using serialize array doesn't give me id
of element . It gives name:value pair

Comment: Is there any possiblity of using serializeArray
and obtaining id also ?